# How to solve set of equations for two unknowns using R?

Tags: r, equation, solver

I have two equations. They are as follows:

```
( 1 - 0.25 ^ {1/alpha} ) * lambda = 85

( 1 - 0.75 ^ {1/alpha} ) * lambda = 11
```

I would like to compute the values of `alpha` and `lambda` by solving the above two equations. How do I do this using R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to translate it into an optimization problem by introducing an loss function:

```
loss <- function(X) {
  L = X[1]
  a = X[2]
  return(sum(c(
    (1 - 0.25^(1/a))*L - 85, 
    (1 - 0.75^(1/a))*L - 11
  )^2))
}

nlm(loss, c(-1,-1))
```

If the result returned from `nlm()` has a `minimum` near zero, then `estimate` will be a vector containing lambda and alpha. When I tried this, I got an answer that passed the sniff test:

```
> a = -1.28799
> L = -43.95321
> (1 - 0.25^(1/a))*L
[1] 84.99999
> (1 - 0.75^(1/a))*L
[1] 11.00005
```

Comment: Oh yes, the answers are matching with what I have. Thanks a ton!

Comment: One doubt @olooney. What does the c(-1,-1) signify within nlm()? For some equations, I received `Error in nlm(loss, c(-1, -1)) : non-finite value supplied by 'nlm'`. However, if I tweak it up to `c(10, 10)` I have received a perfect result. How do I determine how to set these parameters?

Answer (score 1):

@olooney's answer is best.

Another way to solve these equations is to use `uniroot` function. We can cancel the `lambda` values and can use the `uniroot` to find the value of alpha. Then substitute back to find `lambda`.

```
f <- function(x) {

  (11/85) - ((1 - (0.75) ^ (1/x)) / (1 - (0.25) ^ (1/x)) )

}

f_alpha <- uniroot(f, lower = -10, upper = -1, extendInt = "yes")

f_lambda <- function(x) {

  11 - ((1 - (0.75) ^ (1/f_alpha$root)) * x)

}

lambda = uniroot(f_lambda, lower = -10, upper = -2, extendInt = "yes")$root

sprintf("Alpha equals %f", f_alpha$root)
sprintf("Lambda equals %f", lambda)
```

results in

```
[1] "Alpha equals -1.287978"
[1] "Lambda equals -43.952544"
```